# EXTJS 5: Get the current cursor position in a textfield or lookupfield

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, cursor

I need to find the current position of the cursor so I can store it in a variable. I've looked at a few SO answers and none have been successful.

What I have so far:

```
function getCaretPos(id) {
    var el = Ext.getCmp(id);
       var rng, ii=-1;
    var currSelection = window.getSelection();
    if(currSelection){
        currSelection.modify("character", el.value.length);
       // get the current position
       // ii = currentPosition
    }
    return ii;
};
```

For example: I have a textfield displaying data.

MYWORD

When I place the cursor between the Y and W it should return 2. I've seen a few examples for older versions of IE but none seem to work for me in Chrome.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textarea=document.getElementById('textarea');

textarea.onclick=function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(textarea.selectionStart);
  },1);
}
```

```html
<input id="textarea" type="text" value="MYWORD">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code in an old version of extjs (2+) on a textfield and it works for me (just tested on IE)

It's about capture the position from the DOM.

```
var position = item.el.dom.selectionStart;
```

In your example it will be like:

```
    function getCaretPos(id) {
        var element = Ext.getCmp(id);
        var currSelection = element.el.dom.selectionStart;
    }
```

If you want to change the position you just need to set de selectionEnd value to the position you want.

```
element.el.dom.selectionEnd = position;
```